# i want to sum up expense totals and return the value as Report total in totalAmount

Tags: django

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, User
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Movement(models.Model):
    startDate = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    recordTime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    endDate = models.DateField(max_length=50)
    purpose = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    noOfDays = models.IntegerField
    vehicleType = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    bookingStatus = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    cancelled = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __dir__(self):
        return self.location + '|' + self.done + '|' + self.cancelled


class Report(models.Model):
    createdOn = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    SubmittedOn = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, 
    null=True,blank=True)
    userName = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    weekNo = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    projectCode = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    totalAmount = models.FloatField(max_length=300, default=0)
    flatsComment = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="")
    financeComment = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.userName + '|' + self.location + '|' + self.weekNo


class Expense(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    item = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    unitPrice = models.FloatField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.FloatField(max_length=100)
    total = models.FloatField(max_length=250)
#views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib import messages
from django.db.models import Avg, Count, Min, Sum
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views import generic
from .models import *
from .forms import *


# Create your views here.
def programme(request):
return render(request, 'prog/prog.html', {})


def create_report(request):
    form = ReportForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    object_list = Report.objects.all()
    if form.is_valid():
        report = form.save(commit=False)
        report.save()
        expense.save()
        report.totalAmount =          Expense.objects.aggregate(Sum('espence_total'))
    return redirect('prog:reports')
else:
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'object_list': object_list
        }
return render(request,'prog/form_create_financial_report.html', context)


class ReportView(generic.ListView):
    totalAmount = Expense.objects.aggregate(sum(expense_total))['totalAmount']
    template_name = 'prog/report_status.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Report.objects.all()


def report_edit(request, report_id):
    report = Report.objects.get(id=report_id)
    form = ReportForm(request.POST or None, instance=report)
    object_list = Report.objects.all()
    if form.is_valid():
        report.save()
        messages.success(request, ('the report has been updated'))
        return redirect('prog:reports')
    else:
        context = {
            'form': form,
            'object_list': object_list
        }
    return render(request, 'prog/form_edit_report.html', context)


def delete_report(request, report_id):
    report = get_object_or_404(Report,id=report_id)
    form = ReportForm(request.POST or None, instance=report)
    object_list = Report.objects.all()
    if form.is_valid():
        report.delete()
        return redirect('prog:reports')
    else:
        context = {
            'form': form,
            'object_list': object_list
        }
    return render(request, 'prog/form_delete_report.html', context)


def report_detail(request, report_id):
    report = get_object_or_404(Report,id=report_id)

    return render(request, 'prog/report_detail.html',{'report':report})


def create_expense(request, report_id):
    form = ExpenseForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    report = get_object_or_404(Report,pk=report_id)
    if form.is_valid():
        expense = form.save(commit=False)
        expense.report =report
       return render(request, 'prog/report_detail.html', {'report':report})
    context ={
        'report':report,
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request, 'prog/form_create_expense.html', context)
```

i want the result to be a summation of all of the expense_total that belong to a report object. whenever a new expense is created it's total should be added automatically to the report_toalAmount.
the report.totalAmount should be automatically filled whenever an expense is created

and passed to a template in report_detail(Listview)

Comment: I would suggest to use signals https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#post-save

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django signal decorators to have functions "listen" to changes in your database.

Something along the lines should work:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Expense)
def update_report(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created: #validate a new object was created and not updated
         report = Report.objects.get() #use the primary key of your report
         report.totalAmount += instance.total
         report.save()
```

We use `post_save` in the signal decorator, that way the function will only execute **after** a model has been created.

the `instance` parameter is the model that has been created we can use it to retrieve the data we require. I advise you read about signals, they come in handy quite often.

Right after the expense has been created the report object will be updated. Just pass it on to your report_detail view as an argument and you should be all set.

As someone has already suggested in the comment section take a look at [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/) for further reading on the subject.